# Search for staff ID in list

Tags: excel

I currently have two columns in an Excel 2010 spread sheet one containing a staff ID which is numeric and then a second column which contains the staff ID and their name e.g.

```
ID                            Staff Name & ID
1234                          Manager 1234 Bloggs
3456                          Admin 1235 Baker
1235
```

The list of ID's is a list of people who have attended a meeting. I want to be able to tell if the staff member(s) has been at this particular meeting.

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing all the ID's are 4 digit long, enter this to the column after name column:
`=IFERROR(MATCH(VALUE(MID(C2,FIND(C2," ")+1,3)),A:A,0)>0,FALSE)`

where column A contains the ID's attended and Column C contains the names always formatted as in the question.